# AutoScroll - problem makeing Gallery(image picker)

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery, image-gallery, autoscroll

Hi 
I have a confusing problem with the Autoscroll implementation in my own app.
I Want too set up a image gallery and when the debugger gets to the part of the code

```
 if (! [thumb isMemberOfClass:[ThumbImageView class]]) continue;
```

i get an error

```
Undefined symbols:   ".objc_class_name_ThumbImageView", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@ThumbImageView in Gallery.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and I dont know what this means
Has anyone meet with this kind of error.It might be the class implementation but i don't know how to implement it. I have just #import-it into my .h file

if there is some other example of an image gallery please send me a link.I need to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the problem.It was the Executable. Works with IOS 4.0 and above :)